# Can I use the MIT license if I use Font Awesome (SIL OFL)?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, mit, ofl

I have a project in which I included libraries of:

- **Bootstrap** v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com) *Licensed MIT*
- **jQuery** v1.11.2 ([jquery.org/license](https://jquery.org/license/)) *Licensed MIT*
- **jQuery UI** v1.11.2 (http://jqueryui.com) *Licensed MIT*
- **jQuery Validation Plugin** v1.11.1 (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) *Licensed MIT*
- **Tingle** v0.11.0 (https://github.com/robinparisi/tingle) *Licensed

  MIT*
- **Font Awesome** 4.7.0 (http://fontawesome.io) Font: *SIL OFL 1.1*,
  CSS: *MIT License*

I am considering making the source public in a Bitbucket repo. But the question is: can I use the MIT license for my project? (All of them are MIT but the fonts of Font Awesome.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [SIL OFL license](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web) grants you permission to redistribute those fonts. Remember, when you license your code (e.g. by placing a LICENSE.txt file in the root directory), you are only licensing *your* code of which you own the copyright. You do not own the copyright on any of the other libraries. Those libraries and fonts allow you to distribute them as you wish but are not giving you ownership of their copyright. To comply with their license, you must include each of their copyright notices in your repo (e.g. inside their respective folders or in the `LICENSE.txt` file, clearly stating which folder is covered by which copyright).

Comment: I have a doubt no I'm doing it: My project has multiple folders. E.g. I have a CSS folder and a JS folder. Each of them have their own specialized files, and e.g. I have bootstrap split on those two files, but algo other libraries. So, should I put all the licenses in the root folder? ALl of them are exactly the same MIT license. So... should I write something like bootstrap-LICENSE.txt? I would like the idea of putting all in the same LICENSE file, but I can't find an exampleto copy :(

Comment: If the projects are contained in their own folders, it is common to leave the licenses in each projects' folders. Being MIT-licensed, you won't have a problem with this. More complicated licenses might specify differently.

Comment: Oh, no. They are mixed. I re-organized them so I just have e.g. a js folder with all the js files from different libraries. Should I copy the text of their license at the top of each file maybe?

Comment: Oh yes, your "Bootstrap-LICENSE.txt" is a good idea. There should be no confusion with that naming scheme.

Comment: If I only expose a single binary file of my app using those fonts, do I legally have to mention any copyrights or licenses?